# No Results when using variable in SQL Select

Tags: sql-server, date

Hello and thank you for your help. My environment is MS SQL 2008.

I have setup some variables to dynamically specify the date range for this query.  The variables are populated with a date, but when i run this I get no results.

```
SELECT [dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate]
FROM [dbo].[prodData] 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,[dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate], 121) > CONVERT(DATETIME, @FiscalStartDate, 121)
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate], 121) < CONVERT(DATETIME, @FiscalEndDate, 121)
ORDER BY [dbo].[prodData].[WorkOrderId]
```

However if I manually put in dates, the query will return the correct number of results. Like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate]
FROM [dbo].[prodData] 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,[dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate], 121) > '2016-03-021'
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate], 121) < '2016-04-22'
ORDER BY [dbo].[prodData].[WorkOrderId]
```

I have tried using all manners of the `CONVERT` statement to get my variables `@FiscalStartDate` and `@FiscalEndDate`.  My current output is `DATETIME` and results in these:

```
FISCAL START
Apr 22 2016 12:00AM
FISCALEND
Mar 21 2016 12:00AM
```

Or if I just do date i get:

```
FISCAL START
2016-04-22
FISCALEND
2016-03-21
```

The DetectionDate field is outputing as YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000 when i just query the first row.

Not Sure where i went wrong here or I am executing stored procedures and then this is the last step of the puzzle.  Everything works if you run it, except the variables in the select statement.

```
DECLARE @CurrentDayOfMonth varchar (2)
DECLARE @BeginFiscalMonth varchar (2)
DECLARE @EndFiscalMonth varchar (2)
DECLARE @CurrentYear varchar (4)
DECLARE @FiscalStartDay varchar(2)
DECLARE @FiscalEndDay varchar(2)
DECLARE @FiscalStartDate varchar(20)
DECLARE @FiscalEndDate varchar(20)

SET @FiscalStartDay = 22
SET @FiscalEndDay = 21
SET @CurrentYear = RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)),4) 
SET @CurrentDayOfMonth = DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())

IF (@CurrentDayOfMonth >= 22)
BEGIN
    SET @BeginFiscalMonth = RIGHT('0'+CAST((DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())) AS varchar(2)),2)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @BeginFiscalMonth = RIGHT('0'+CAST((DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())-1) AS varchar(2)),2)
    SET @EndFiscalMonth = RIGHT('0'+CAST((DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())-2) AS varchar(2)),2)
END

SET @FiscalEndDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),(@CurrentYear + @EndFiscalMonth + @FiscalEndDay),110)
SET @FiscalStartDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),(@CurrentYear + @BeginFiscalMonth + @FiscalStartDay), 110)
```

DetectionDate is DATETIME, not null in the table.

Comment: what is the data type for `[DetectionDate]` column ?

Comment: Are you storing dates as varchar? You should definitely change the column type

Comment: Show us the part of the code where you declare and populate the variables.

Comment: Added the declarations, and DetectionDate type.  I feel that I don't know the SQL syntax well enough to accomplish what I want.  Seems long winded to me...

Comment: @EndFiscalMonth  doesn't get assigned if the day is 22 or greater.

Comment: My bad, it does, removed one too many lines of comments  `SET @EndFiscalMonth = RIGHT('0'+CAST((DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())-1) AS varchar(2)),2)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the appropriate data type for the data you are using. for instance `DetectionDate` column should be a date/datetime data type.

Your query should be as simple as

```
Declare @FiscalStartDate DATE = '20160321'; --<-- use YYYYMMDD 
Declare @FiscalEndDate   DATE = '20160422';

SELECT [DetectionDate]
FROM [dbo].[prodData] 
WHERE [DetectionDate] > @FiscalStartDate
AND   [DetectionDate] < @FiscalEndDate
ORDER BY [WorkOrderId]
```

the above query is sargable, it would use indexes defined on the date column. avoid unnecessary data type conversion.

Comment: This is short, simple, to the point  and most excellent, except I need to build the date declared.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some print statements were added i found the problem. Here is the corrected select statement

```
SELECT *
FROM [LAW_Dump].[dbo].[prodData] 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[LAW_Dump].[dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate],121) > @FiscalEndDate
AND CONVERT(DATE,[LAW_Dump].[dbo].[prodData].[DetectionDate],121) < @FiscalStartDate
ORDER BY [LAW_Dump].[dbo].[prodData].[WorkOrderId]
```

It wasn't returning any results because I had my dates backwards in my SELECT statement.  Thank you all.